# Inequality between union-closed families of sets and corresponding upward-closed families

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

This question is about an inequality for union-closed families of sets related to [Frankl's conjecture](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00373-014-1515-0.pdf) and a [result by Reimer](https://search.proquest.com/openview/c4aa1a45607ee595b6756a458728de8a/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=33829). It relates the union-closed families and corresponding upward-closed families (or filters).

Let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ (where $[n] = \{1, ..., n\}$) be a union-closed family of sets, i.e., if $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$, then also $A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$. Assume $|\mathcal{A}| > 1$.

Let $\mathcal{U} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ be a filter (or upward closed family) corresponding to $\mathcal{A}$ ([see Lemma 1.3. here](https://search.proquest.com/openview/c4aa1a45607ee595b6756a458728de8a/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=33829)). I.e., $\mathcal{U}$ satisfies:

1. $\mathcal{U}$ is a filter: For all $U \in \mathcal{U}$ and $U\subseteq V \subseteq [n]$ it also holds $V \in \mathcal{U}$.
2. There is a bijection from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{U}$, $A \mapsto U_A$ such that: If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $A \subseteq U_A$ and if $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$, $A \neq B$, then $[A, U_A] \cap [B, U_B] = \emptyset$.

Hereby, $[A, U_A] = \{\hat{A} \subseteq [n] : A \subseteq \hat{A} \subseteq U_A\}$.

For $x \in [n]$, denote by $\mathcal{A}_x = \{A \in \mathcal{A} : x \in A \}$ and $\mathcal{U}_x = \{U \in \mathcal{U} : x \in U\}$.

**Question:**
Does the following inequality hold?
$$
\sum_{x = 1}^n |\mathcal{A}_x|^2 \geq \sum_{x=1}^n |\mathcal{U}_x|\,(|\mathcal{U}| - |\mathcal{U}_x|)
$$

**Comments:** I tested the inequality for quite a few examples, but I am stuck trying to prove it. While in the [paper by Reimer](https://search.proquest.com/openview/c4aa1a45607ee595b6756a458728de8a/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=33829) there are many inequalities relating union-closed families and their upward-closed counterparts, none seems to cover the above inequality.